# Giving Alert Message in HTML if Url cannot be loaded

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using html and jquery. In my page I am opening an URL, if that URL is failed to open, 'Problem Load Page' or 'Server not found' error is displaying in webpage. How can I throw an Alert Box instead of showing error message webpage.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do You mean by opening URL?

Comment: opening a website like 'https://www.google.co.in/'

Answer (score 2):

you can check with ajax if page exists, and then redirect to it.

```
<a href="/somelink" id="test1">Link1</a> <span id="result1"></span>

$.ajax($("#test1").attr("href"), {
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      $("#result1").html("not working");
    },
    200: function() {
      $("#result1").html("working");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why it always return statuscode 200, no matter what url we have in href? check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MT6YH/)